# How can I easily find an equation for the terms in a series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was given this problem on a test:

> *Find an equation for the terms in this series: 1, 5, 29, 173, 1037*

Now the only way I can even think to do is either common difference, or common ratio.

Trying common difference shows the next pattern to be *4, 24, 144, 864*. So obviously the sub-pattern is represented by $4*6^{n-1}$. Now how do I get a general equation for the entire series from that?

I thought maybe I could plug in the equation for the sub series into $d$ in the equation:

> $a + (n-1)*d$,

since that's the standard equation for an arithmetic series, but of course that doesn't work because the arithmetic series equation always references the first term.

No clue how to do this.

**Ideally I just want to know if there's a general rule for an equation when you have to go multiple levels deep into common difference or common ratio, or both.**

For example a harder one is: 3, 5, 13, 85, 3613. So common difference (CD) gives: 2, 8, 72, 3528. Then the next pattern if I used common ratio (CR) would be, 4, 9, 49, ... . Then the next pattern from CD would be 4, 40, ...

Is it even meaningful to alternate between CD and CR in this manner?

Comment: There is no general rule.  Many people on this site complain about problems like this, because there is no guarantee that the pattern you found continues.  Differences are one approach, and work very well with polynomials.  Please note that your 4*(6^n-1) needs the parentheses fixed-you mean 4*6^(n-1).  It is certainly possible to alternate between differences and ratios.  Once you find a pattern you believe, you can work backwards to translate it into a pattern for the original sequence.

Comment: @RossMillikan Okay well assuming the series does continue, how would I go from an equation for a sub-series into an equation for the whole? Such as on Leox's answer below.  The sub-series is 4*6^(n-1), which looks very similar to the final pattern, but n-1 turns into just n, and the ratio of 1/5 came from somewhere

Comment: Far from an answer, but still a useful old friend of a tool for reference in case you were not familiar with the [database](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+5%2C+29%2C+173%2C+1037&language=english&go=Search).

Comment: Thanks.  So is there no easy way to go from the equation for the sub-series to the equation for the entire series?

Answer (score 1):

$$ \frac{4 \cdot 6^{n-1}+1}{5}$$

The general rule is called the Calculus of finite differences.
We  have 
\begin{gather*}
b_1=a_2-a_1,\\
b_2=a_3-a_2,\\
\ldots \\
b_{n-1}=a_n-a_{n-1}.
\end{gather*}
Then $b_1+b_2+ \cdots +b_{n-1}=a_n-a_1.$
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} b_i=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}4\,{6}^{n-1}=4 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}{6}^{n-1}=4 \cdot \frac{6^n-6}{30}.
$$
Then 
$$
a_n=4 \cdot \frac{6^n-6}{30}+1=\frac{4 \cdot 6^{n-1}+1}{5}
$$

Comment: Okay I can see that works, but I don't understand how to go from 4*(6^n-1) to that

Comment: If $d_n = a_n - a_{n-1}$, then $a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n d_k + C$.  So (in this case) you have to do the sum of a finite geometric series.

Comment: That is interesting, because your equation models the series with n starting at 0, yet wolfram alpha gives an entirely different equation, that models the series with n starting at 1 http://wolfr.am/19J6HcX