# Find the value of the series $\frac{8}{5} + \frac{16}{65} + \frac{24}{325} + \frac{32}{1025} + ...$ to 20 terms.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

> Find the value of the series
> $$\frac{8}{5} + \frac{16}{65} + \frac{24}{325} + \frac{32}{1025} + ...$$
> to 20 terms.

The numerator seems to follow a clearly defined pattern here: it is an AP with common difference of 8. However, I cannot seem to find a pattern for the denominator here. The ratios are $13, 5, 3.15$ etc. whereas the differences are $60, 260, 700$. Even the double differences are not seemingly following a pattern. One last thing I noticed was that $5 = 2^2+1$, $65 = 8^2+1$, $325 = 18^2+1$, $1025 = 32^2+1$. The numbers $2,6,18,32$ are again not in an obvious pattern.

What is the answer to the problem? Finding the nth term is also good enough, as I should be able to take it from there.

Note: I read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/528736/how-can-i-easily-find-an-equation-for-the-terms-in-a-series) question, and the topic behind these kind of problems seems to involve the calculus of finite differences. If someone could also point to some resources regarding this topic, I would read up more on this as well.

Comment: impossible without more context

Comment: @Integrand Why so? A more concrete reason?

Comment: why not have the denominator be $19$ or $\pi$ or whatever nonzero number you please?

Comment: Where did you get this question from? Perhaps they made some typo.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh this was from a test paper I was attempting. I haven't made a typo copying the question, although the problem setters may have made one. I'll try to dig up a solution (if I can find one) and update the question if that adds more "context".

Comment: $2, 8, 18, 28$ are twice the squares of the natural numbers or $f(x) = 2x^2$.

Comment: The denominator seems to be $4n^4+1$.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A211412 gives $\{ 4n^4+1 \}_{n=1} =5, 65, 325, 1025, 2501, 5185, \ldots $

Comment: @JaapScherphuis indeed looks like it. How'd you get that!?

Comment: To be frank there does not appear a clear pattern. And as far as finite differences are concerned any 4 numbers can be general be made to fit a unique cubic polynomial in $n$ so that these numbers are its value at $n=1,2,3,4$.

Comment: If you're not sure, you can always use Lagrange interpolation, which graphing software (e.g Desmos) can do.

Comment: Using your observation that it was one more than the squares of 2,8,18,32, I saw the same as Toby Mak that these were twice the squares 1,4,9,16. This gives $((2n)^2)^2+1=4n^2+1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an exhaustive answer: As pointed out by others, **the series is not defined well enough**. Lagrange interpolation of the first four values gives the cubic
$$40x^3-140x^2+200x-95$$
This also passes through the same points as $x^4+1$ does.

[image]

To uniquely determine the sequence $4x^4+1$, the 5th value of the sequence, i.e. $2501$ is required, as that would yield a fourth-degree polynomial.

[image]

As the other answers have already pointed out, once we obtain $T_r = \frac{8r}{4r^4+1}$, solving the problem becomes much easier.
$$\begin{gather}
S = \sum_{r=1}^{20} \frac{8r}{4r^4+1} \\
= \sum_{r=1}^{20} \frac{2}{2r^2-2r+1} - \frac{2}{2r^2+2r+1} \\
= 2\left(1 - \frac{1}{841}\right) \\
\boxed{S = \frac{1680}{841}}
\end{gather}$$

Thank you to everyone who gave their inputs.

Answer (score 7):

I believe your sum was intended to be

$$\sum \frac{8k}{4k^4+1}$$
And notice the denominator can be written as $(2k^2-2k+1)(2k^2+2k+1)$

Comment: ...and telescope!

Comment: This is a special case of the [Sophie-Germain identity](https://brilliant.org/wiki/sophie-germain-identity/) where $b = k, a = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Partial fractions gives:
$$A(2k^2 - 2k + 1) + B(2k^2 + 2k + 1) = 8k$$

and substituting $k = 0, 1$ gives $A = 2, B = -2$. Now:

$$f(k)=\frac{2}{2k^2-2k+1} - \frac{2}{2k^2+2k+1}$$

$$f(k+1)=\frac{2}{2k^2+2k+1} - \frac{2}{2(k+1)^2+2(k+1)+1}$$

and the sum telescopes. So $S_{20}$ is:

$$\frac{2}{2(1)^2-2(1)+1} - \frac{2}{2(20)^2 + 2(20) + 1}$$